# Как сделать проверки на requests.get("https://pastebin.com/raw/WdXuJnN2").json()

Tags: python, requests

Например, если паста https://pastebin.com/raw/WdXuJnN2 не доступна, или удалена, то он обращяется к другой пасте (тобиш резервную), а если уже она не доступна, то он выведит ошибку в плане print('Paste deleted')

попробовал так, но не работает

```py
    mainJson = requests.get("https://pastebin.com/raw/0tEKwzzn").json()
    if mainJson["IsEnabled"] == False:
        print("Falsed!")
    elif mainJson["IsEnabled"] == True:
        print("Trued!")
```

Comment: Не работает потому что вы сравниваете строку с булевым выражением

Answer (score 0):

Почекайте HTTP-код ответа от Pastebin, наверняка там будет 404:

```
response = requests.get(url)
if response.status_code != 200:
    // Что-то пошло не так, обрабатываем
   ...
else:
    // Всё идёт по плану
    mainJson = response.json()
    ...
```

Comment: Нет 200 возвращает, в браузере.

Comment: Можно пример урлы, по которой паста недоступна, но сайт всё равно возвращает 200? Прям не верю я, что Пастбин настолько наплевательски к этому отнеслись

Comment: Специально сделал для теста исчезающую пасту: https://pastebin.com/A4cc3t8m - пока она доступна, Пастбин возвращает 200; при попытке её открыть по истечении срока хранения Пастбин возвращает ожидаемые 404. Проверял с помощью https://httpstatus.io/ и для https://pastebin.com/A4cc3t8m , и для https://pastebin.com/raw/A4cc3t8m. Что значит фраза "возвращает 200 в браузере"? То, что страница открывается и на ней не написано большими цифрами "404", ещё не значит, что у неё статус 200. Этот код только в теле ответа видно, а на экране можно всё что угодно написать.